# Can browser plugins be made to run in Electron as-is?

Tags: electron

For my Electron app I would like to access Wacom tablet with all the special data it can offer. Without doing anything I can still use wacom tablet as a standard mouse-like input, but I want device specific data like tip pressure, etc.

I notice that Wacom provides browser plugins on Windows and OSX which allow a web page to access Wacom tablet functionality through Javascript. Chrome is on the supported list of browsers. So I'm wondering if it's possible to get that plugin to work with Electron. Any thoughts?

Comment: Windows only but there is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wintab